# Does Redis rebuild its cache from replicas if a FLUSHALL is run on just the primary node?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

We have 4 nodes in a AWS ElastiCache Redis cluster (running on r3.large) and I wanted to perform a flush on the entire db, ran a FLUSHALL on just the primary node, but cache count came back to its' prior state

1. Does a `FLUSHALL` not remove all keys from all nodes within the cluster? If not, how would you go about doing so?
2. Did Redis rebuild its' cache from replica nodes after a `FLUSHALL`?

Image is of the `Current Items (Count)` metric in CloudWatch:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`FLUSHALL` is designed to remove all keys and the cluster **should not** use the data in the slaves to "rebuild" itself. It should stay empty.

This sounds like an issue with ElastiCache. I'm guessing that it incorrectly identifies the `FLUSHALL` operation as a failure of the master - perhaps because of the time it requires - and fails over to one of the slaves. Either contact the support for assistance, or try turning off the slaves before performing the flush.